# <figure> with figcaption or headling?

Tags: css

Can i use multiple figures for images with different captions? Or mabye shoud use div with headling for new image? 
Example:

```
<figure>
 <figcaption>XXX</figcaption>
 <img src="image/jmv.png" alt="XXX">
</figure>
<figure>
 <figcaption>XXX</figcaption>
 <img src="image/jmv.png" alt="XXX">
</figure>
```

Comment: You could also use a single figure with multiple images

Comment: Yeah i know, but i need caption for each one

Comment: Yes...you can...that is the intended use. Read the [**Spec**](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/grouping-content.html#the-figure-element)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [`figure`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-figure-element) element may contain several images, but it can contain at most one `figcaption` element, which thus works as a caption for the entire element. There are various other ways to associate caption texts with images; after all, we used captions before `figure` was invented. Somewhat naivistically, you could use e.g. the following approach:

```html
<figure>
  <figcaption>Two random images</figcaption>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100/people" alt="(image 1)">
      <td>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100/nature" alt="(image 2)">
    <tr>
      <td>
        A random image of people.
      <td>
        A random image of nature.      
  </table>
</figure>
```

Alternative you could use several `figure` elements, each with one image and a `figurecaption`, and you could wrap the `figure` elements, and possibly a heading element for them, inside a `div` element or a `section` element.

Within either choice, there is much variation. The choice of the approach and the variation is mainly a matter of taste and coding standards, though it may also be affected by technical considerations. Some approaches can be more suitable for styling or scripting purposes, in a particular context.